# WIndows SDK installation: missing import library

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdk

Windows 7 Pro.

I'm trying to install WIndows SDK. There were a few attempts:
Firstly I've installed Visual C++ build tools 2015 preview (just a commend line toolkit for a building win apps.
After that, I'm trying to build my project (CMake based), but cmake shows me the error

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'advapi32.lib'

all other core import libs located here (default installation of the latest SDK) :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\"

However - no advapi32.lib there.
I've tried to install SDKs 7, 8, 8.1, 10 but with the same result - no this lib there.

Any idea how to solve the problem please?

Comment: Your Windows SDK install went wrong at some point. All of the SDKs installed on my machine have appropriate *AdvAPI32.lib* import libraries (e.g. for the Windows 10 SDK at *<SDK dir>\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64*). As for CMake (which apparently raises the error): I'm not aware whether it can be used with the Visual C++ Build Tools, or requires a full Visual Studio installation. You might want to try installing [Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

Comment: tried to use VS Community also without success...

Comment: Is something deleting advapi32.lib behind your back?

Comment: looks yes, and my next installings didn't restore this (and many other libs ) oddly

Answer (score 0):

don't understand why , but found that SDK Setup doesn't install all files,
a lot of libs and includes are missed. Copied these manually from SDK pacjage

Comment: This is not a solution. You need to investigate, why this is happening, and solve the root cause. Blindly copying files around will break, sooner or later. Start by turning off your anti-virus software, and see if that changes anything. Also check your disk for errors.

Comment: you are right, as I understand my steps should first of all to remove all SDKs and VC/VS. after that an installing SDK but which one should be used? I see WinSDK 7 (I'm on WIndows 7) but I'm not sure that will be compatible with VC19 from Visual C++ BUild Tools 2015... Need latest compiler for C++14 features. and previously I was using SDK10